# warning unsigned long to int in C language

Tags: c

I'd have a quick question over my codes:

```
int main(void)
{
    int i,j,key[5][5],ikey[5][5],row,col,plen,suc;
    int devide,count,h,k,no,p1[100],e1[100],d1[100];
    char p[100],e[100],d[100],clen;

    printf("Enter your plaintext::::::::");
    gets(p);
    plen = strlen(p); // this line gets error
```

warning line is:

```
plen = strlen(p);
```

**implicit conversion loses integer precision unsigned long to int.**

Comment: What is the question? Is it that `strlen` returns the type `size_t`?

Comment: I'm working through some exercises and have got a warning that states: implicit conversion loses integer precision unsigned long to int.
`plen = strlen(p);` this line.

Comment: `strlen` returns a value of type `size_t` which is a typedef for `unsigned long int` on your machine.

Comment: You said that, but what are you asking? Are you asking why the compiler says you cannot fit a "quart into a pint pot"?

Comment: for exp this line gets no error `clen=strlen(e);
    devide=(clen+1)/suc;` because clen is char but plen is integer. i couldnt understand why i got the error.

Comment: @skrtbhtngr how can i fix it?

Comment: Please be precise: a warning is not an error. The `clen=strlen(e);` should also give a warning.

Comment: @misshyde: Try to use `unsigned long` for `plen`. Or better use `size_t` for portability.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned the function `strlen(p)` returns a value of type `size_t`. Here is an abstract from the C99 standard:

> size_t
>
> which is the unsigned integer type

Now the point here is that what exact type it is(`unsigned`, `unsigned long` etc.) is actually implementation-defined, which means it varies depending on the platform. Obviously you have it defined as `unsigned long` which means that by

```
plen = strlen(p);
```

you convert `unsigned long` to `int` which the compiler can't ignore because in some cases this conversion may lose the value's precision.

Answer (score 1):

The correct declaration:

```
#include <stddef.h>

size_t plen;
// ...
plen = strlen(p);
```

As others have already pointed out, `strlen()` returns a `size_t`.